# Delegate method in UITableView doesn't get call after passing data to it via protocol in Detail View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, protocols

Imagine you have a UITableView called A.

In A, you implement a delegate method to print data that is passed to it via a protocol defined in a detail view controller called B.

In the A.m implementation file of A you have the following code:

```
#import "A.h"
#import "B.h"

@interface A()
@end

@implementation

//bunch of methods not relevant to this question first

//Implement method that passes myStringData sent back from B to A
#pragma mark - Send data back to cell tapped in feed

-(void)sendDataBackToA:(NSString *)myStringData 
{
if ([myStringData rangeOfString:@"Ciao_Bello"].location == NSNotFound)
   {
    NSLog(@"The string delegate back to A in case 1 is %@", myStringData); 
   }

else
   {
   NSLog(@"The string delegate back to A in case 2 is %@", myStringData); 
   }

}
```

In the B.h header, you declare the relevant protocol and delegate:

```
@protocol senddataProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)sendDataBackToA:(NSString)myStringData
@end

@interface B: UIViewController<UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, assign)id<senddataProtocol> stringDelegate;
@end
```

When implementing B.m, you make sure to synthesize your delegate property and call the delegate method in viewWillDisappear, printing the NSString you are passing:

```
@implementation B
@synthesize stringDelegate;

//A few methods' implementations not relevant to this questions first

//Call delegate method to pass data from B to A in viewWillDisappear
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   if ([self.button.titleLabel.text rangeOfString:@"text1"].location == NSNotFound)

   {
    [stringDelegate sendDataBackToA:@"Ciao_Bello"];
    NSLog(@"The string delegate sent from B to A is %@", @"Ciao_Bello");
   }

else
   {
    [[stringDelegate sendDataBackToA:@"Forza_Italia"];
    NSLog(@"The string delegate sent from B to A is %@", @"Forza_Italia");
   }
}
```

And you run your build.

You see @"Ciao_Bello" and @"Forza_Italia" printing properly in your log when you segue from B to A, depending on the NSString value set for the button in B (self.button.titleLabel.text).

But you also see in your log that the sendDataBackToA delegate method is never called in A.

What do you need to do to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you set the `stringDelegate` property of B?

Comment: I don't...  That's where the problem is I believe.  In the segue to B should I do `B.stringDelegate=self;` then to set it?

Comment: Yes. That is where you would typically do it

Comment: What's the proper way to set the delegate?  When I try 'B.stringDelegate=self; in the segue to B it gives me a warning: !Assigning to 'id<senddataProtocol>' from incompatible type 'A *const__strong'.

Comment: Does your declaration of A state that it implements the protocol?

Comment: I don't have anything in A.h that references the protocol.  The declaration of the protocol is in B.h only.  I thought that's where I had to put it since the B view controller is the one to send the information back to A.  Value your expertise.

Comment: Your declaration for A would be something like `@interface A : UIViewController <senddataProtocol>`. It will work without this because objective c resolves the selector dynamically at run time, but declaring support for the protocol avoids the compiler warning

Comment: Imported "B.h" to "A.h" and added protocol senddataProtocol to my list of protocols there.  This removed the warning and runs great.  Thanks!